# Program that can create equation from numbers and result?

Tags: programming, math

I need something, that can do this thing:

> I have number 5, 5 and result 25. The program return 5*5. Another
>   example: I have 7 and result 49. The program return 7². (of course
>   with more complex equations)

Simple:

```
input 5;5 = 25
output = 5*5

input 5;2;4 = 7
output = 5-2+4
```

Also it will be good if program will be in console, so I can implement it with other programs.

Comment: you are asking to solve an equation for operators. an operator can also be expressed as a function, and there are functional equation solvers in the popular math softwares. see a related math exchange, and also check out the Wikipedia link in the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525914/solving-equations-where-the-solution-is-an-operator